# Generating seeds to tables not represented by a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If in my rails application I have an intermediate table that represents the associations between two objects (like, books and authors: a book has many authors and an author has many books), how can I populate this table with the `seeds.rb` file?

**update**

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :books  
    # ...
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
    # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between the two. If that is the case, then you could do something like:

```
# seeds.rb
author = Author.create(name: 'Mark Twain')
author.books << Book.new(title: 'The Adventures of Tom Sawyer')
```

Another thing to check is: is your model-less table properly named: `authors_books`?

Or try writing as such, which will raise more useful errors because of the bang `!` if it fails:

```
# seeds.rb
author = Author.create!(name: 'Mark Twain')
author.books.create!(title: 'The Adventures of Tom Sawyer')
```

Comment: I am getting `NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
`

Comment: Post your `app/models/book.rb` and `app/models/author.rb` files and I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Why isn't there a model representing this data? In most cases, you want a model representing any information that you are storing in a database.

Once you have the model, you should be able to create your seeds easily by doing something as simple as

```
BookAuthors.create([
            {book_id: 1, author_id: 2}
        ])
```

In your seeds.rb file.